# Do graph_tool property maps work in GraphViews?

Tags: python, graph-tool

The `GraphView` object in the python `graph_tool` package does not seem to work as I expect when the base graph is itself a `GraphView` object. Here is some code that shows the issue:

```
from graph_tool import *
import numpy as np

g = Graph()
p1 = g.new_vertex_property("bool")
gv1 = GraphView(g, p1)
p2 = gv1.new_vertex_property("bool")
gv2 = GraphView(gv1, p2)

print gv1.num_vertices()
```

This prints 0 as expected; we haven't added any vertices.

```
v = g.add_vertex()
p1[v] = True
print gv1.num_vertices()
```

This prints 1 as expected. Changing the property map updates the view.

```
for w in gv1.vertices():
    p2[w] = True
print gv2.num_vertices()
```

This prints 0, which I did not expect. Changing the property map doesn't seem to update the view.

```
p2[v] = True
print gv2.num_vertices()
```

Using the vertex objects from `g` instead of `gv1` doesn't seem to help; 0 is again printed.

```
gv2 = GraphView(gv1, p2)
print gv2.num_vertices()
```

This prints 1, suggesting that the problem is not with the property map but, somehow, the view.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When GraphView objets are *composed*, i.e. generated from another GraphView object, the underlying property maps need to be combined, using `numpy.logical_and()`, which means it needs to be *copied*. So, in your example, the internal property map used by `gv2` will be a *copy* of `p2` combined with `p1`, so that if you modify either `p1` or `p2`, it will no longer affect `gv2`, after it's created.

If you want to alter the map used by `gv2`, you can obtain it with `gv2.get_edge_filter()`.

Comment: Thanks! For what it's worth, in my application, I'm passed gv1 and a helper function for "creating" new neighbor nodes, and I have to be agnostic about whether the helper function is creating the nodes or just exposing them via a GraphView. It appears that maintaining this agnosticism is possible but requires a bit of care.